# "WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable" and Pyomo (OS: Windows)

Tags: anaconda, spyder, pyomo, ipopt

I have been trying to make ipopt work on pyomo. I've downloaded pyomo (version 5.7.3) and ipopt using Anaconda Navigator and I'm using Spyder to edit and run my `.py` codes. I've been using the following code from the pyomo tutorial in order to understand whether ipopt is successfully installed and works.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.nVars = pyo.Param(initialize=4)
model.N = pyo.RangeSet(model.nVars)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=pyo.Binary)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.summation(model.x))
model.cuts = pyo.ConstraintList()
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.solve(model) 

# Iterate, adding a cut to exclude the previously found solution
for i in range(5):
   expr = 0
   for j in model.x:
       if pyo.value(model.x[j]) < 0.5:
           expr += model.x[j]
       else:
           expr += (1 - model.x[j])
   model.cuts.add( expr >= 1 )
   results = opt.solve(model)
   print ("\n===== iteration",i)
   model.display()
```

When I set `opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')` and run the code, it gives me the following warning:

```
WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver ipopt
```

My first try to solve this problem by myself is to manually download the `ipopt` executable (ipopt 3.11.1-win64) from the link below:

```
https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/
```

Afterwards, I extracted the files and placed them into the `pyomo` solver location:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers
```

This didn't work, so I also tried specifying the path to the `ipopt` executable using the code:

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory("ipopt", executable="C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ipopt\bin\ipopt.exe")
```

However, doing this gives me the following warning:

```
WARNING: Failed to create solver with name 'ipopt': Failed to set executable
    for solver ipopt. File with name=C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\
    pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ipopin\ipopt.exe
    either does not exist or it is not executable. To skip this validation,
    call set_executable with validate=False.
```

Reminder that the part `ipopin\ipopt.exe` was not a typo. I don't know why it happened. I also tried copy-pasting the executable outside the `bin` folder and placing it in the `ipopt` folder instead:

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory("ipopt", executable="C:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ipopt\ipopt.exe")
```

Unfortunately I still get the `WARNING. Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver ipopt` in the end.

I also tried downloading the `ipopt` executable from the link below but `ipopt.exe` is eliminated by my virus scanner as it considers the downloaded file as a threat:

```
https://projects.coin-or.org/CoinBinary/browser/binary/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.13.2-win64-msvs2019-md.zip?rev=1072
```

Is there another way I can try to make IPOPT work in this case?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? My virus scan eliminates the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

[if](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc4mU.jpg) you run your jupyter notebook from the anaconda then you should be able to see your solver in the installed list of anaconda